# Why Pylons allowing duplicate action in same controller

Tags: python, pylons

Anyone knows why Pylons allowing duplicate action in same controller instead of throwing error?
And the controller ignores first duplicate action and always serves the second duplicate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

being python the second function definition overrides the first.

drop this code in a file called test.py

```
# test.py
def my_func():
    print "i will never get called"

def my_func():
    print "awesome"

my_func()
```

and run it

```
$ python test.py
awesome
```

no errors, same applies for methods on objects.